# How can i add border to the asp.net detailsview commandrow cell?

Tags: asp.net, css, detailsview

i have a problem on below image:
[image]

I have detailsview, but i can't show border left and right on commandrow cell. Here is the css codes:

```
 .dvCommandRow td
{
    border-right: solid 1px #B4B4B2;
    border-left: solid 1px #B4B4B2;
    text-align: right;
    padding: 5px;
    /* border:solid 1px #B4B4B2;  I deleted but still problem continue */
}

.dvCommandRow td a
{
    color: #3e6d8e;
    background-color: #e0eaf1;
    border: 1px solid #7f9fb6;
    margin-top: 2px;
    margin-right: 2px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    margin-left: 0pt;
    padding-top: 3px;
    padding-right: 4px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    padding-left: 4px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 90%;
    line-height: 2.2;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.dvCommandRow td a:hover
{
    background-color: #3e6d8e;
    color: #e0eaf1;
    border: 1px solid #33ccff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Where is the problem that causes to unbordered row?

If you need to see generated html code:

```
    <table class="dv" cellspacing="0" border="0" id="ctl00_cpholder_dvKurumEkle" style="height:50px;width:550px;border-collapse:collapse;">
    <tr class="dvHeader">
        <td colspan="2">
        <div class="dvHeaderLeft">
        </div>
        <div class="dvHeaderCenter">
            KURUM EKLE</div>
        <div class="dvHeaderRight">
        </div>
    </td>
    </tr><tr class="dvRowEven">
        <td class="dvField">Kurum Kapsamı</td><td>
                <input id="ctl00_cpholder_dvKurumEkle_cbSgKapsamindaEkle" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$cpholder$dvKurumEkle$cbSgKapsamindaEkle" checked="checked" onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$cpholder$dvKurumEkle$cbSgKapsamindaEkle\',\'\')', 0)" /><label for="ctl00_cpholder_dvKurumEkle_cbSgKapsamindaEkle">SGK</label>
                    <input id="ctl00_cpholder_dvKurumEkle_cbHastaAdinaKurum" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$cpholder$dvKurumEkle$cbHastaAdinaKurum" onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$cpholder$dvKurumEkle$cbHastaAdinaKurum\',\'\')', 0)" /><label for="ctl00_cpholder_dvKurumEkle_cbHastaAdinaKurum">Hasta Adına</label>
            </td>
    </tr><tr class="dvRowOdd">
        <td class="dvField">Üst Kurumu</td><td>
                <select name="ctl00$cpholder$dvKurumEkle$ddlUstKurumEkle" id="ctl00_cpholder_dvKurumEkle_ddlUstKurumEkle">
            <option value="0">&#220;st kurumu yok.</option>
            <option value="5">D&#214;NER SERMAYE</option>
            <option value="2">VALİLİK</option>
            <option value="3">MALİYE &#214;DEMELİ BAKANLIK</option>
            <option value="4">KAYMAKAMLIK</option>
            <option value="8">SGK</option>
            <option value="9">BELEDİYE</option>
            <option value="10">MALİYE BAKANLIĞI</option>

        </select>

            </td>
    </tr><tr class="dvRowEven">
        <td class="dvField">Kurum Adı</td><td>
                <input name="ctl00$cpholder$dvKurumEkle$txtKurumAdiEkle" type="text" maxlength="100" id="ctl00_cpholder_dvKurumEkle_txtKurumAdiEkle" onkeyup="SAPHastaKurumAdiOtomatikTamamla(this,'kurumAdi');" />
                <span id="ctl00_cpholder_dvKurumEkle_reqFieldKurumAdiEkle" style="color:Red;visibility:hidden;">*</span>
                <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$cpholder$dvKurumEkle$hdnHasta_id" id="ctl00_cpholder_dvKurumEkle_hdnHasta_id" />

                <div id="kurumAdi">
                </div>
            </td>
    </tr><tr class="dvRowOdd">
        <td class="dvField">Vergi Dairesi</td><td>
                <input name="ctl00$cpholder$dvKurumEkle$txtVDEkle" type="text" maxlength="50" id="ctl00_cpholder_dvKurumEkle_txtVDEkle" />
            </td>
    </tr><tr class="dvRowEven">
        <td class="dvField">Vergi Numarası</td><td>
                <input name="ctl00$cpholder$dvKurumEkle$txtVNEkle" type="text" maxlength="50" id="ctl00_cpholder_dvKurumEkle_txtVNEkle" />
            </td>
    </tr><tr class="dvRowEven">
        <td class="dvField">SAP Kodu</td><td>
                <input name="ctl00$cpholder$dvKurumEkle$txtSapEkle" type="text" id="ctl00_cpholder_dvKurumEkle_txtSapEkle" onkeyup="SAPHastaKurumAdiOtomatikTamamla(this,'sapKodlari');" />
                <span id="ctl00_cpholder_dvKurumEkle_reqFieldSapKoduEkle" style="color:Red;visibility:hidden;">*</span>

                <div id="sapKodlari">
                </div>
            </td>
    </tr><tr class="dvRowOdd">
        <td class="dvField">Yetkili Adı Soyadı</td><td>
                <input name="ctl00$cpholder$dvKurumEkle$txtYetkiliAdSoyadEkle" type="text" id="ctl00_cpholder_dvKurumEkle_txtYetkiliAdSoyadEkle" />
            </td>
    </tr><tr class="dvRowEven">
        <td class="dvField">Yetkili GSM</td><td>
                <input name="ctl00$cpholder$dvKurumEkle$txtYetkiliGSMEkle" type="text" id="ctl00_cpholder_dvKurumEkle_txtYetkiliGSMEkle" />
                <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$cpholder$dvKurumEkle$txtYetkiliGSMEkle_MaskedEditExtender_ClientState" id="ctl00_cpholder_dvKurumEkle_txtYetkiliGSMEkle_MaskedEditExtender_ClientState" />
            </td>
    </tr><tr class="dvRowOdd">
        <td class="dvField">Yetkili Tel</td><td>
                <input name="ctl00$cpholder$dvKurumEkle$txtYetkiliTelEkle" type="text" id="ctl00_cpholder_dvKurumEkle_txtYetkiliTelEkle" />
                <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$cpholder$dvKurumEkle$txtYetkiliTelEkle_MaskedEditExtender_ClientState" id="ctl00_cpholder_dvKurumEkle_txtYetkiliTelEkle_MaskedEditExtender_ClientState" />
            </td>
    </tr><tr class="dvRowEven">
        <td class="dvField">Yetkili E-Posta</td><td>
                <input name="ctl00$cpholder$dvKurumEkle$txtYetkiliEpostaEkle" type="text" id="ctl00_cpholder_dvKurumEkle_txtYetkiliEpostaEkle" />
            </td>
    </tr><tr class="dvCommandRow">
        <td colspan="2"><a href="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$cpholder$dvKurumEkle$ctl04&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, true))">Kaydet</a>&nbsp;<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cpholder$dvKurumEkle','Cancel$-1')">Vazgeç</a></td>
    </tr><tr class="dvFooter">
        <td colspan="2">
        <div class="dvFooterLeft">
        </div>
        <div class="dvFooterCenter">
        </div>
        <div class="dvFooterRight">
        </div>
    </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the class="dvField" that you declare on all of the other cells is not declared in your command row.

Also I notice that in the ".dvCommandRow td" section of your stylesheet, you are declaring border-left and border-right and then you are overriding by declaring border.